# Cascading Dropdown list JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo 2 select de Ciudad y Localidad, los cuales se llenan desde un Array en JS, el problema es que al seleccionar la Ciudad, las localidades correspondientes se me llenan pero con la posición y no con el valor, es decir, en lugar de tener "Loc 1", "Loc 2", obtengo 0,1.

```
var dptosLocs = {
  Ciudad1: ["Loc1", "Loc2"],
  Ciudad2: ["Loc3", "Loc4"],
  Ciudad3: ["Loc5"],
  Ciudad4: ["Loc6"],
};

obtenwindow.onload = function () {
  var dptoSelect = document.getElementById("departamentos");
  var locSelect = document.getElementById("localidades");

  for (var dpto in dptosLocs) {
    dptoSelect.options[dptoSelect.options.length] = new Option(dpto, dpto);
  }

  dptoSelect.onchange = function () {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    locSelect.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var loc in dptosLocs[this.value]) {
      locSelect.options[locSelect.options.length] = new Option(loc, loc);
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) itera las propiedades del objeto, en este caso, índice o posición que, para el objeto principal es correcto, desde `Ciudad1` hasta `Ciudad4`.

Pero, para los arreglos internos debes usar [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) para iterar valores en vez de propiedades:

```js
var dptosLocs = {
  Ciudad1: ["Loc1", "Loc2"],
  Ciudad2: ["Loc3", "Loc4"],
  Ciudad3: ["Loc5"],
  Ciudad4: ["Loc6"],
};

// En el primer paso es correcto iterar propiedades
for(let dpto in dptosLocs) {
    console.log(dpto);
}

// En el segundo se trebaja de forma diferente
let value = 'Ciudad1';

// Iterando propiedades, usas la variable loc como índice
// Y debes hacer referencia al objeto original
for(let loc in dptosLocs[value]) {
    console.log(dptosLocs[value][loc]);
}

// Iterando valores, solo necesitas la variable loc
for(let loc of dptosLocs[value]) {
    console.log(loc);
}
```